# How to extract sentences which has similar meaning/intent compared against a example list of sentences

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, gensim, doc2vec, sentence-similarity

I have chat interaction [Utterances] between Customer and Advisor and would want to know if the advisor interactions contains particular sentences or similar sentences in the below list:

Example sentences i am looking for in the Advisor interactions

````
["I would be more than happy to help you with this",
"I would be happy to look over the account to see how I can help get this sorted out for you",
"I’d be more than happy to look into this for you!",
"Oh, I see, let me assist you with this concern.",
"I am more than happy to do everything I can to resolve this matter for you.",
"I would be happy to look over the account to see how I can help get this sorted out for you.",
"I am happy to have a look."]


I have a dataset which contains the list of interaction_id and Utterances(Sample below)

```Example Chat interaction between Advisor and CLient : 
Client : Hello I would like to place an order for replacement battery
Agent: Hi Welcome to Battery service department. I would be happy to help you with your battery replacement Order.
````

How do get/Extract the sentences with similar intent or meaning.
I am newbie to NLP and i believe I have a sentences classification/Extraction problem in hand and would like to know is there any way i can achieve what i need

Basically I am trying to achieve the below:

```
ID    Utt                                               Help_Stmt_Present

IRJST   Hi Welcome to Battery service department. 
        I would be happy to help you with your battery
        replacement Order.                                     Yes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be multiple ways for doing this in multiple steps: 
**1. Calculating sentence vectors**

> a. Using pretrained word embeddings(glove, word2vec, fasttext, etc) and calculating word embeddings for each word and then average it across words of the sentence to calculate the sentence embedding. 
>   b. Use [Universal Sentence Encoder](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/hub/blob/50bbebaa248cff13e82ddf0268ed1b149ef478f2/examples/colab/semantic_similarity_with_tf_hub_universal_encoder.ipynb) to get the sentence embeddings.

**2. Calculate similarity match**

> a. Calculate the distance between between the target and all other N sentences using euclidean or cosine or any other distance metric that works best for your problem. 
>  
>   b. Train a KNN model with N sentence vectors you have and apply K-NN prediction with the target sentence to get K most similar sentences.

To get even better results you can use deep learning based techniques and SOTA architectures such as transformers and the architectures built over it. You can checkout [this repository](https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers) which solves your task using transformers. Also to play with different architectures and other NLP tasks you can checkout the [Hugging Face Repository](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers)

Comment: Thanks Akash. Appreciate your quick response.So If i understand correctly, I have to use universal sentence encoder for all  my  sentences in the sentence_list =[ "I would be more than happy to help you with this",
"I would be happy to look over the account to see how I can help get this sorted out ] and do a similarity match with utterances in my training dataset .Is that correct?

Comment: Yes that is one quick method you can use.The notebook linked here provides the code for your use case! Maybe you can start with that one and improvise on it.